# For Loop with Invalid response for a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, input

Definitely still learning/a newbie and using this to learn about dict.
The goal here:

1. Allow a user to create a menu with items(keys) and prices(value)
2. User creates items (can be alphanumeric)
3. User creates prices for items (numeric only)

Issue I'm running into is the for loop on the pricing the items is not repeating the same step when an invalid value is added. What is the simple way to fix this?

```
def createMenu(menu):
    while True:
        userMenu = input("Create menu and prices for each item and enter a blank to proceed.\nSo what is the new item?\n" + str(len(newMenu) + 1) + " ")
        if userMenu == '':
            break
        menu.update({userMenu: ''}) 
        print(menu)
    return menu
        
def createPrice(menu):
    
        while True:
            for k in menu:
                userPrice = input("Enter price for " + k + ":\n")
                if userPrice.isdecimal():
                    userPrice = float(userPrice)
                    menu[k] = userPrice
                else:
                    print("Enter a valid value!")
                    continue
            return menu
```

I was thinking of adding an extra IF statement where it checks for previous value to equal "". But was wondering of other work arounds

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).  And for future questions, please don't forget to tell us what language you're programming in, by adding it as a tag.

Comment: For each menu-item, you want to loop until the user gives a valid price. So that's what you have to implement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)